# CelID based location in Android?

Tags: android, iphone, gps, triangulation

A lot has been said on SO about Celids and how we use them to get a rough estimate of a user's position. Most famously, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82184/public-cell-id-databases).

In Android can the app developer get lat/lon by simply querying the SDK? Or do they still have to match the Cell-ID against a webservice or a public db?

According to [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance), you can make the following call to get "location information". Is this information lat/lon?

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

If that is indeed true, is there a limitation on the number of queries per day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code, as you mention it, will give you network estimated location :

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);`

It does more than cell-id (mobile network location), because it can give you wifi/internet connexion location too.

There is no limitation on the number of queries per day.

The above code let you register the locationListener. In the location listener you have to implement a method `onLocationChanged(Location location)`. All new location will be sent to this method and you can get lat/lon with Location object.

You can register GPS Location listener too. It works exactly the same way.

I have no clue for iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. just to confirm, anybody with an Android doesn't need to depend on public CellID Dbs for querying location? Would you know since when this has existed?

Comment: I don't know since when this exists. But I have been using it for more than 2 years with android. This functionnality is part of android. I don't know exactly in the background which servers are used to get these locations.